Integrating Elevenlabs Stream into PyVoip Call with G.711 PCMA Codec
I'm trying to get an Elevenlabs audio stream into a PyVoip phone call, but the audio quality is extremely poor. Using Wireshark, I confirmed that the RTP stream negotiates the G.711 PCMA codec. However, Elevenlabs doesn't offer this format directly, so I'm having trouble making the audio sound good over the phone.
I've tried several different conversion methods to make the Elevenlabs stream compatible with G.711 PCMA, but nothing has worked so far. All I hear on the phone is heavy noise and crackling. I expected the audio to be clear once converted properly, but I'm unsure where things are going wrong. Does anyone have experience with this and can offer advice on the correct conversion process?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
